# Python Packages Installed with Pip are not Able to be Accessed on M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1, python-venv, pylance

For some reason pip packages that I install in a venv or globally in my system are not able to be accessed from within files to run code.

Overview of my system: Macbook Pro 13-inch, M1, 2020

From the cli I run `which python3` and get `/usr/local/bin/python3`

So now let's install Flask and create a Flask app.

```
pip3 install Flask
```

So now I open  a file `app.py` in Vs Code or with nano in a Mac system terminal and make a basic Flask app.
In VS Code it says `"flask" could not be resolved Pylance`

Well that's obviously not good but for demonstration purposes let's finish a basic Flask
app:
from flask import Flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

But let's try to run the app. I run `python3 app.py`
But here's what I get from VS Code:

```
File "/Users/matt/Projects/practice/server/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
```

Here's the mac terminal:

```
File "/Users/matt/Desktop/test/app.py", line 1
    import flask from Flask
```

Since I mentioned the `venv` before let's see what the `venv` is telling us.
Fire we create it:
`python3 -m venv .venv`

Then we activate:
`source .venv/bin/activate`
It shows `Py server` in the bottom right of my console, so we know it's active.

Inside we install Flask:
`pip3 install Flask`

So now in the directory we run `which Flask` and get `/Users/matt/Projects/practice/server/.venv/bin/flask`

So my cli says that Flask is there.
But if we try to `import flask from Flask` and run the code we get this error:
`Import "flask" could not be resolvedPylance`

Obviously there is something wrong going on where because when I run commands packages are able to be seen as installed, but then when you try to write code, the installed packages cannot be resolved by Pylance.

Please let me know if anyone knows if this is an issue with my M1 Mac or if there is a better way to check and reset the path so that things can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a VS Code issue. Pylance is a language server that's used by VS Code.

You showed that you can find the installed package inside your virtual environment. You can verify it by running `source .venv/bin/activate`, then `python`, and in the interactive prompt importing flask: `from flask import Flask`. This should run smoothly.

Now all that's left is to point Pylance to this virtual environment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters

Comment: it's not just vs code. when I try to run the code from the mac built in system terminal it says this `python3 app.py
  File "/Users/matt/Desktop/test/app.py", line 1
    import flask from Flask
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and has an arrow pointing to the `from` in `import flask from flask`

Comment: here's a list of the installed packages in the venv from the Mac system terminal `❯ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
click              8.1.3
Flask              2.2.2
importlib-metadata 6.0.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.1
pip                21.2.4
setuptools         57.4.0
Werkzeug           2.2.2
zipp               3.11.0`

Comment: Sorry, I gave you syntactically wrong import statement. Try `from flask import Flask`. What it says in the error is that it's a syntax error. That's not a problem with a packaging system, you would see `ModuleNotFoundError` in that case. Also, case is important. `from flask import flask` will not work.

Comment: File "/Users/matt/Projects/bad-practice/server/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: In my answer I was talking about the interactive prompt inside activated virtual environment with `flask` installed, outside of VSCode and any files.